# C++ armadillo sparse matrix batch insertion

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, armadillo

I am looking at batch insertion for sparse matrices in armadillo in the docs "http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#batch_constructors_sp_mat".

It defines form1 as:

form 1: sp_mat(rowind, colptr, values, n_rows, n_cols)

What does colptr hold?  If I understand correctly, it should have the actual address to whatever columns we want to insert at ?

Seems strange to me rowind are not pointers but colptr are pointers.  Any reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Armadillo uses the standard Compressed Sparse Column (CSC) format for storing sparse matrix data. The format is also known as Compressed Column Storage (CCS) and Harwell-Boeing.  The row indices and column pointers are explained on several sites:

- Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_column_.28CSC_or_CCS.29
- Netlib: http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node92.html
- http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~mroberts/toolbox/c++/sparseMatrix/sparse_matrix_compression.html

The CSC format is used for compatibility with existing sparse solvers, etc.